# Maple / Linear Algebra - Transpose -> find two unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, maple

I have the matrix

### T = [[-cos(x), sin(x)sin(y), cos(x)sin(y)],

### [0, -cos(x), sin(y)],

### [sin(x), cos(x)sin(y), cos(x)cos(y)]]

And I want to find x and y were 0 =< x =< pi and 0 =< y =< pi, so
that T:(1,2,0)->(0,-2,2).

How do I do that in Maple 18? Have tried for hours but cannot seem to find the Maple function for that. Anything to point me in the right direction would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot the two points. $T:=[[],[],[]] $.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am new to this site and is not really sure how to make good formatting

Comment: See [how to format math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [how to format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single Maple function to solve this. The right approach is to form the Matrix product `v := T . <1,2,0>` and then use the `solve` command to solve the set of equations `{v[1]=0, v[2]=-2, v[3]=2}` for x and y.  Assuming no typos in the OP's question, there does not appear to be any `x` and `y` that satisfy this over-constrained problem.